# When implementing monorepo, where should I place configuration files such as webpack, eslint?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

#### directory structure

```
project
│   README.md
│   .gitignore
│   package.json
│
└───packages
│   │
│   └───A
│   │   │   package.json
│   │   │   index.html
│   │   └───src
│   │ 
│   └───B
│   │   │   package.json
│   │   │   index.html
│   │   └───src
│   │ 
│   └───common
│       │   package.json
│       └───src
└───.git
    │    
    └───.husky
```

I want to implement `A`, `B` and `common` packages as `monorepo`.

Since they all use `React`, the same lint rules (`.eslintrc.js`, `.prettier.json`) can be applied.
Also, the configs related to `babel`, `webpack`, and `ts` are all the same (using the same plugin and loader).

Therefore, I want to place lint configs and files such as `babel.config.json`, `tsconfig.json`, and `webpack.config.js` in the root workspace.

But I don't know how to set some path related settings.

ex) alias

```
 // babel.config.json

 "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["."],
        "alias": {
          "@": "./src/",
          "@assets": "./src/assets/",
          "@components": "./src/components/",
          "@pages": "./src/pages/",
          "@services": "./src/services/"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

In this case, is it generally correct to put webpack.config.js or tsconfig.json("paths") for each package?

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate workspace with the configs

```
project
│   README.md
│   .gitignore
│   package.json
│
└───packages
│   │
│   └───A
│   │   │   package.json
│   │   │   index.html
│   │   └───src
│   │ 
│   └───B
│       │   package.json
│       │   index.html
│       └───src
│     
└───configs
│
│   └───eslint
│   │   └───configs
│   │   │       eslintrc.js
│   │   │   package.json
│   │   │   index.js
```

`eslintrc.js` contains the shared eslint config.
`eslint/package.json` the reference to index.js and the required devDependencies.

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/eslintconfig",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "private": true,
  "main:": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "12.4.1"
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```
const eslintConfig = require('./config/eslintrc')

module.exports = eslintConfig
```

The eslintconfig then can be added to to packages a,b, etc. by creating an `.eslintrc.js` which imports the shared config.

```
const globalConfig = require('@myanwb/eslintconfig');
module.exports = {
  ...globalConfig,
};
```

Add the eslint dependency to the `package.json` of the package using

```
    "@myorg/eslintconfig": "*",
```